# Converting TreePaths into a JTree

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I am using Java. I have a set of `Treepaths` from a `JTree`. Now I want to create a `JTree` from it. Can anyone explain how it can be achieved?

Example:

- Root

  1. Colors

     - Red
     - Green
  2. Animals

     - Cat
     - Rat

I had paths from `Root->Colors->Green` and `Root->Animals->Rat`. By using this - how to create a tree?

Answer (score 2):

I can't see any problem with that, with [this tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html) you need to start, examples [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/Catalog0240__Swing.htm)